# open iframe and select an element inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open up a site in an iframe and be able to select its elements:

```js
function addIframe() {
    const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.id = 'cambridge-iframe';
    iframe.src = 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/provenance';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);


    setTimeout(() => {
        const frame = $('#cambridge-iframe');
        const selected = frame.contents().find('#stateHdr');
        console.log(selected.length)
    }, 10000);
    
}
```

The above code adds the iframe with the id but returns no selected element .

How can we do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because of cross origin policy

Comment: Why not use `.load()`? Or JSONP?

Comment: how?????????????????????